# Sending Fax with OpenText fax server

Tags: .net, jakarta-ee, fax, opentext

We have installed OpenText fax server and its in production. Now we have a requirement to develop web service (in .Net or JAVA) that can communicate with OpenText server and send/ receive fax. Is there any code sample or document from where I can get idea? Is there any API that we can use for this purpose?

I am looking for API/ Integration help to integrate with OpenText fax server RightFax version 10.

Few connectors/ service are available on [OpenText](http://faxsolutions.opentext.com/messagemanager-resources.aspx) for this purpose but they required licences.

Comment: Open Text has plenty of servers. Which product do you have in mind? (Livelink, Content Server, Archive Server, Presentation Server, Fax Server)?

Comment: I am looking for API/ Integration help to integrate with OpenText fax server RightFax version 10.